# ERROR_BAD_LENGTH при вызове Process32First()

Tags: c, winapi

Есть такая функция:

```
DWORD GetProcessPID(char **ExesNames, short int count, short int *out_index)
```

Тело:

```
HANDLE hsnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
PROCESSENTRY32 process;
DWORD proc_ID = -1;
short int i;
_Bool state = FALSE;

if(Process32First(hsnapshot, &process))
{
    while(Process32Next(hsnapshot, &process))
    {
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(stricmp(process.szExeFile, ExesNames[i]) == 0)
            {
                proc_ID = process.th32ProcessID;
                state = TRUE;
                *out_index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(state) break;
    }
}

CloseHandle(hsnapshot);
return proc_ID;
```

В чем суть: сама эта функция загнана в цикл и на первом проходе все прекрасно, все работает, но но после выполнения этого кода:

```
void DestroyProcess(DWORD PID)
{
   HANDLE proc_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
   printf("Destroying process\n");
   TerminateProcess(proc_handle, 9);
   CloseHandle(proc_handle);
}
```

функция GetProcessPID(), ломается и просто пропускает условия. GetLastError() сообщает об ошибке ERROR_BAD_LENGTH, но я не представляю как с ней бороться. подскажите пожалуйста какими способами можно победить эту ошибку.

Comment: Вы, кажется, забыли про отладчик...

Comment: Нет, не забыл про отладчик. Он ничем помочь не может. GetLastError(), кстати, находит ошибку 24: "The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect.", но я новичок в winapi и мне это ни о чем не говорит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметр `lppe` у `Process32First` помечен как `_Inout_`, т.е. это еще и входной параметр, и он должен быть правильно инициализирован.

> The calling application must set the dwSize member of PROCESSENTRY32 to the size, in bytes, of the structure.

Вы не устанавливаете `process.dwSize`, по этому возникает ошибка `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`.

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо. В следующий раз буду внимательнее читать msdn :)